# getting 404 with $http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, api

```
csMgmtApp.controller('launchedController', ['$scope', '$http', '$document', '$resource', function ($scope, $http, $document, $resource) {

    $scope.clientResult = {};
    $scope.data = {};

    $document.ready(function () {
        var query_string = {};
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }
        if (typeof(query_string.access_token) != "undefined") {
            var result = {};
            result.state = query_string.state;
            result.scope = query_string.scope;
            result.access_token = query_string.access_token;
            result.expires_in = query_string.expires_in;
            result.resource_server_base_uri = query_string.resource_server_base_uri;
            result.token_type = query_string.token_type;
        }

        $scope.clientResult = result;

    });

    console.log($scope.clientResult);

        $scope.startSessionPayload = {
            'stationPhoneNumber': '5555555555',
            'inactivityTimeout': '0',
            'inactivityForceLogout': 'false'
        };

    $http({
        'url': $scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri  + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers':{'Authorization': 'bearer ' + $scope.clientResult.access_token,'content-Type': 'application/json'},
        'data': JSON.stringify($scope.startSessionPayload)
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log('data', $scope.data)
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = status;
    });

}]);
```

---

The code above gives me a 404 when I try te $http "POST".

When I console.log($scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri), I get: "https%3a%2f%2fapi-c7.incontact.com%2finContactAPI%2f".

But, I get a 404, and when I look in developer tools, I see it's trying to post to : `"http://localhost:63342/Call_cntr/client/https%3a%2f%2fapi-c7.incontact.com%2finContactAPI%2fservices/v6.0/agent-sessions"`

I'm starting to think it's failing because the "://localhost..." is being "prepended" to the base_uri... Not sure why this is happening. I feel I'm providing everything mentioned in the inContact API docs. Maybe it's with my angular conversion from AJAX to $http ??

Any help, much appreciated, I'm stuck..

> Once you have an API Authentication Token, you use this token to create an agent session for the agent whose credentials you used to get the token. This is done by requesting the https://api-{cluster}.incontact.com/inContactAPI/services/v6.0/agent-sessions method, and supplying either a "station ID" or a phone number which will be delivered to the agent.

per the docs : https://developer.incontact.com/API/AgentAPI#!/Sessions/startSession

Comment: For testing purposes, can you hardcode the url to be sure it points to the inContact server rather than using `$scope.clientResult.resource_server_base_uri` (which seems to incorrectly be pointing to your localhost)?

Comment: Would you enter `http%3a%2f%2stackoverflow.com/` in your browser or rather `http://stackoverflow.com/`?

Comment: What is the correct URL you should to post?

Comment: Hey guys, I'll try all of these solution. And, I'll update my question with the corrrect url. I would use http://stackoverflow.com/, but the http%3 is what I'm getting back from the API. Is there a way to parse that?  Isin't %3 = : , and %f = /  ,  in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
result.resource_server_base_uri = unescape(query_string.resource_server_base_uri);
```

I believe that  `/` is actually a seperator, but `%2f` becomes an ordinary character that simply represents `/` character in your url.

`unescape()` is deprecated; try `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Awesome. I"m getting somewhere, getting a 401 - unauthorized now, but that's a new problem. unescape worked.. even though, my editor is trying to tell me it's depreciated..

Comment: coincedentally, this solved the 401, by applying the unescape to the auth_token as well..  If you don't mind schooling someone, why was it returned in the wrong format from the API, and why was it neccessary to unescape?

Comment: If others come onto this decodeURI can be used in place of unescape.

Comment: I wish I suggested `decodeURIComponent()` in the first place.  I'm glad you got it sorted out.